# How do I sort a bit complex paginated array with SUM, COUNT and GROUP BY in CakePHP?

Tags: php, sorting, cakephp, pagination

My pagination settings look like this:

```
        $this->Paginator->settings = array(
            'limit' => 100,
            'order' => 'Traffic.accessed DESC',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Traffic.webmaster_site_id' => $this->WebmasterSite->find('list', array(
                    'fields' => 'WebmasterSite.id',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'WebmasterSite.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
                    )
                ))
            ),
            'fields' => 'DATE(Traffic.accessed) AS `access_date`,
                        SUM(Traffic.webmaster_site_transfer) as total_webmaster_income,
                        COUNT(Traffic.webmaster_site_id) as total_webmaster_clicks',
            'group' => 'DATE(Traffic.accessed)',
            'paramType' => 'querystring'
        );

        $click_data = $this->Paginator->paginate('Traffic');

        $this->set('click_data', $click_data);
```

And in view

```
<th class="text-center">
    <?php if ($this->Paginator->sortKey() == 'Traffic.total_webmaster_clicks') {
        if ($this->Paginator->sortDir() == 'asc') {
            $sort_icon = '<i class="icon-sort-up"></i> ';
        } else {
            $sort_icon = '<i class="icon-sort-down"></i> ';
        }
    } else {
        $sort_icon = '<i class="icon-sort"></i> ';
    } ?>
    <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Traffic.total_webmaster_clicks',$sort_icon.__('Total Clicks'),array('escape'=>false)); ?>
</th>
```

So by `Traffic.total_webmaster_clicks` it does not sort. Note that this comes from `AS total_webmaster_clicks` in pagination statement.

I don't understand how can I use sorting with such kinds of (AS selected) fields and GROUP BY. plus I cannot create virtualFields because there's a GROUP BY for a DATETIME field.

Thanks.

Comment: You can always create virtual fields - and this is what you should and need to do here. Group by still works!

Comment: Problem is that I get `subquery contains more than one rows` when using virtualFields, because traffic table has many webmaster_site_id.

Comment: That is not an issue with virtual fields, but with the query itself. Failure by design, thus it cannot work with or without virtual fields. afaik COUNT() doesn't work the way you want it to work here.

Comment: If there is no way to change your query, you will have to rewrite the model's paginate, and possibly paginatecount functions to be able to handle total_webmaster_clicks.  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#custom-query-pagination

Answer (score 0):

For complex query default sorting is not work, So you should create a view and use view same as model, you will definitely get pagination with sorting. And by using view your application performance will also increase